# extjs: how can I add event handlers to a component in its raw object form (xtype)

Tags: javascript, html, extjs, ria

I have an extjs component in its raw object type, for example:

```
var x = {
   xtype: 'button', 
   text: 'Delete', 
   handler: whatever, 
   more:config, 
   more2: config2};
```

Now I want to add some listener to x. In my scenario I don't have access to the `x` object before or right after it is created. I just want to add an event handler when it is just a javascript object without overwriting existing handlers. How can that be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the listeners config to do this

```
{
   xtype: 'button', 
   text: 'Delete', 
   handler: whatever, 
   more:config, 
   more2: config2,
   listeners:{
      scope : this,
      event1 : function(){},
      event2 : function(){}
   }
```

};

Answer (score 4):

A `listeners` config is needed:

```
var x = {
   xtype: 'button', 
   text: 'Delete', 
   handler: whatever, 
   more:config, 
   more2: config2,
   listeners: {
     click: function() {
       ...       
     },
     render: function() {
       ...
     }
   }
};
```